# Effect of multiple backlinks with different anchor text from same site

Tags: seo, backlinks

So if you took videos and photos for a website, would

> [Photography](http://google.com) and [Videography](http://google.com) by [Company Name](http://google.com)

offer any SEO advantage over

> [Photography and Videography by Company Name](http://google.com)

I understand that multiple links from the same site aren't treated equally, but what if they have different anchor text?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at it as a User, it answers the question. The first link takes the user to their destination, the follow up links are not needed so close by for the same purpose. They are redundant. On the other hand a link above the fold and one below the fold makes sense as once user scrolls, the earlier navigation element is gone.

So, in this specific case the second makes sense for the user and most likely also for the search engines. The anchor text is also easier to read and understand.